# Melhorias no EntityManegedFactory JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Pessoal estou trabalhando da seguinte forma , eu tenho 2 `PersistenceUnit` , um do banco de dados do Gestor , que e onde eu encontro os dados dos bancos de dados dos clientes ,outra do banco de dados dos clientes , que pego a partir dos dados do Gestor, quero saber se estou fazendo da maneira certa, ou se posso melhorar, tenho vários clientes acessando simultaneamente o sistema hoje, então se alguém tiver alguma dica !

**Conexão**

```
    package DAO;

import static DAO.DAO_001_Gestor.mitryusEM;
import Entity.Cadgru;
import Entity.UsuarioSessao;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class Conexao implements Serializable {

     //Cria o EMF do Gestor
    public static EntityManagerFactory GestorEMF;
    //Cria oS EMF do Banco de dados dos clientes
    private static Map<String, EntityManagerFactory> mitryusEMF = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static EntityManagerFactory usuario;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager(String PU, String Local, String endfdb) {
        // Verifico se o retorno esta vindo do GestorPU ou do MitryusPU 
        //Caso seja do Gestor o PU E igual a 0
        if (PU.equals("0")) {
            //Verifica se ja tem EMF do gestor aberto
            if (GestorEMF == null || !GestorEMF.isOpen()) {
                //Caso nao tenha Cria o EMF
                GestorEMF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("GestorPU");
                return GestorEMF.createEntityManager();
            } else {
                //Caso tenha cria o EM
                return GestorEMF.createEntityManager();
            }
            //Caso seja o MitryusPU OBS(Vem da Variavel PU)
        } else if (mitryusEMF.get(Local) == null || !mitryusEMF.get(Local).isOpen()) {
            //Cria as Propriedades de Conexao
            Properties props = new Properties();

            props.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:firebirdsql:" + endfdb + "/3050:" + Local);
            mitryusEMF.put(Local, Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PU, props));
            //Guarda o Local obs(Endereco do banco de dados ex c:\banco ) em uma sessao
            HttpSession sess = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
            sess.setAttribute("mitryusEMF", Local);

            //Retorna o EM
            return mitryusEMF.get(Local).createEntityManager();

        } else {
            HttpSession sess = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
            sess.setAttribute("mitryusEMF", Local);
            return mitryusEMF.get(Local).createEntityManager();
        }
    }

    //Pega o EM do Gestor
    public EntityManager getEntity() {
        if (GestorEMF == null || !GestorEMF.isOpen()) {
            GestorEMF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("GestorPU");

            return GestorEMF.createEntityManager();

        } else {

            return GestorEMF.createEntityManager();
        }
    }

    //Pegao em do Banco de dados do cliente
    public EntityManager getEntityMitryus() {
        //String que recebe o valor da sessao "mitryusEMF"
        String valor = (String) getSession().getAttribute("mitryusEMF");
        //Retorna o EM do cliente 
        return mitryusEMF.get(valor).createEntityManager();
    }

    public HttpSession getSession() {
        return (HttpSession) getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    }

    public FacesContext getFacesContext() {

        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    }

    /**
     * @return the mitryusem
     */
}
```

**Persistence** :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="GestorPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>Entity.Cadgru</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:firebirdsql:10.1.1.122/3050:C:\BANCOS\GESTOR.FDB"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="SYSDBA"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="masterkey"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="2000"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  <persistence-unit name="MitryusPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>Entity.Cadusr</class>
    <class>Entity.Cadloj</class>
    <class>Entity.Cadfun</class>
    <class>Entity.Tipcli</class>
    <class>Entity.Tipven</class>
    <class>Entity.Vendas</class>
    <class>Entity.Venda_Sintetico</class>
    <class>Entity.CodigoPin</class>
    <class>Entity.Codloc</class>
    <class>Entity.VendaEvolucao</class>
    <class>Entity.Reljva</class>
    <class>Entity.Venda_Moeda</class>
    <class>Entity.Venda_Moeda_Loja</class>
    <class>Entity.Vendas_OP_Caixa</class>
    <class>Entity.P563_Vale</class>
    <class>Entity.P571_ValeExpirado</class>
    <class>Entity.P527_AnaliseCliente</class>
    <class>Entity.Cadpla</class>
    <class>Entity.Cadfor</class>
    <class>Entity.GraficoVendas_Funcionario</class>
    <class>Entity.P530_TicketMedio</class>
    <class>Entity.P495_OrcamentosPendentes_S</class>
    <class>Entity.P495_OrcamentosPendentes_A</class>
    <class>Entity.P535_AlteracaoVendas</class>
    <class>Entity.Detusr</class>
    <class>Entity.P468_VendaFaixaValor</class>
    <class>Entity.Tipfor</class>
    <class>Entity.P444_ContasPagar</class>
    <class>Entity.P444_ContasPagar_DATVEN</class>
    <class>Entity.P444_ContasPagar_TOTALIZADO_PCONTAS</class>
    <class>Entity.P444_ContasPagar_MesAno</class>
    <class>Entity.P444_ContasPagar_Sintetico</class>
    <class>Entity.P507_VendasAnaliseGeral_A_Mestre</class>
    <class>Entity.P507_VendasAnaliseGeral_A_Detalhe1</class>
    <class>Entity.P507_VendasAnaliseGeral_A_Detalhe2</class>
    <class>Entity.P507_VendasAnaliseGeral_S</class>
    <class>Entity.Cadpag</class>
    <class>Entity.P493_ValeFuncionarios</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="SYSDBA"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="2000"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="masterkey"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Felipe, criei uma resposta baseada nos meus comentários e que também tenta responder à sua pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É um assunto extenso e complexo, então vou tentar algumas sugestões pontuais, mas cabe a você julgar se seriam boas dentro do contexto do seu projeto.

## Injeção de dependências

Uma melhoria seria usar injeção de dependências usando uma API padronizada ao invés de depender de chamar uma classe própria.

Tem um artigo que explica como usar praticamente a mesma abordagem de manter um `EntityManagerFactory` por banco, mas permitindo injetar o `EntityManager` de forma transparente:

> [JPA Multitenancy](http://tomas-dvorak.cz/posts/jpa-multitenancy)

## Não usar a sessão desnecessariamente

Outra coisa que não vejo necessidade é usar a sessão se você já mantém uma lista estática dos EMFs.

Porque não acessa diretamente por um método estático ou melhor ainda, como mencionei acima, injetando com CDI ou Spring?

## Não criar um `EntityManagerFactory` por banco

Também não gosto da ideia de manter muitas instâncias de `EntityManagerFactory` em memória.

Se o número de clientes crescer você vai ter um consumo exagerado de memória.

Você poderia usar um `EntityManagerFactory` para todos os clientes e manipular o `DataSource` para ir no banco correto.

Note que isso só funciona bem quando todos os clientes estão na mesma instância do banco, porém em *schemas* ou usuários diferentes, de forma que você pode reaproveitar as mesmas conexões do pool e apenas redirecionar a conexão para o *schema* correto.

Basicamente isso funciona colocando uma lógica no método `getConnection` do `DataSource` usado na sua aplicação, de forma que a conexão retornada esteja apontando para o banco correto.

Como toda a arquitetura de acesso ao banco no Java, mesmo usando Hibernate, passa pelo `getConnection`, isso funcionaria de forma transparente para sua aplicação.

Um exemplo de um `DataSource` real, porém removidas as partes específicas, seria o seguinte:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DelegatingDataSource;

/**
 * Set schema dynamically when a new connection is created.
 * It depends on the request.
 */
public class ContextDelegatingDataSource extends DelegatingDataSource {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContextDelegatingDataSource.class);

    public ContextDelegatingDataSource(DataSource dataDource) {
        super(dataDource);
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        final Connection con = super.getConnection();
        String schemaName = currentContextSchema();
        con.createStatement().execute(MessageFormat.format("set search_path to ''{0}''", schemaName));
        return con;
    }

    protected String currentContextSchema() throws SQLException {
        Integer idCliente = ContextoDaRequisicao.getIdCliente();
        return idCliente.toString();
    }

}
```

Essa implementação funciona com o banco PostgreSQL 9.x.

Quanto ao `ContextoDaRequisicao.getIdCliente()`, este método iria recuperar o ID do cliente de uma variável `ThreadLocal`, isto é, armazenada no contexto da requisição atual. A variável deve ser definida em um *servlet filter* ou *interceptor*. No sistema em questão, um `HandlerInterceptor` (Spring) salva o ID do cliente baseado na URL, pois cada cliente acessa um *path* diferente, tipo `sistema.com.br/id-cliente/funcao-do-sistema`.

## Considerações

Se você não tem muita familiaridade com os conceitos, isso pode ser bem complicado e talvez não valha a pena o esforço.

Entretanto, numa aplicação que tem algum potencial de crescimento vale a pena investir um pouco numa solução melhor que guardar muita coisa em memória. Talvez a ajuda de um arquiteto ou desenvolvedor mais experience seja um diferencial.

Comment: Realmente vou precisar estudar sobre isso, pois vai ter muita gente acessando a app , qualquer duvida eu posto aqui !!!